# What makes an extremum independent of the integration interval?

Tags: mathematical-physics, calculus-of-variations, boundary-value-problem, initial-value-problems, euler-lagrange-equation

This is a problem related to Mechanics. There is a physical quantity called the action, that is given by:

$$S[\mathbf x]=\int\limits_{t_A}^{t_B}L(t, \mathbf x(t), \dot{\mathbf x}(t))\mathrm dt\tag{1}$$

where

$$\dot{\mathbf x}(t):=\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\mathbf x\tag{2}$$

Hamilton's principle requires $\mathbf x$ (the trajectory of a particle) to be an extremum for $S$, subject to the conditions

$$\mathbf x(t_A)=\mathbf x_0, \ \ \ \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\mathbf x\Bigg\vert_{t=t_A}=:\dot{\mathbf x}(t_A)=\mathbf v_0.\tag{3}$$

But I believe something important would be that for a given $t_A, \mathbf x_0$ and $\mathbf v_0$. The solution $\mathbf x(t)\vert_{(t_A, t_B)}$, restricted to the interval of interest, should be independent of the choice of $t_B$. Otherwise it would be like the particle was "seeing into the future" to adjust its trajectory in order to make $S$ an extremal. This would make no sense in Physics.

My concern rises from looking at the problem of *minimal surface of revolution*. In that problem, the solutions to the Euler-Lagrange equation do not account for all points in the plane, I made a graph:

[image]

The black lines are some solution to the equation, and they are confined to a limited region in the plane. I could envision "stitching together" several catenaries to reach point $Q$, but the problem is that such a solution is no longer an extremum, the actual extremum is given by the red dotted line.

I know the underlying problems are somewhat different because in Mechanics we don't fix the $t_B$ endpoint, but looking at the figure, if I fix the starting point $P$, and the derivative then I have singled out one of the catenaries and I will never be able to reach point $Q$ unless I do the stitching... Even then, the solution is not an extremum.

So, my question is, is there a way to guarantee that for $t_A<t_B<t_C$, and given the initial conditions $\mathbf x_0$ and $\mathbf v_0$, the solutions to

$$S[\mathbf x]=\int\limits_{t_A}^{t_B}L(t, \mathbf x(t), \dot{\mathbf x}(t))\mathrm dt,\tag{4}$$

$$\bar{S}[\bar{\mathbf x}]=\int\limits_{t_A}^{t_C}L(t, \bar{\mathbf x}(t), \dot{\bar{\mathbf x}}(t))\mathrm dt,\tag{5}$$

satisfy the condition

$$\bar{\mathbf x}(t)\vert_{(t_A, t_B)}=\mathbf x(t).\tag{6}$$

Is it somehting that is trivially satisfied when you use "initial conditions" instead of "boundary conditions"? or is it necessary to impose some restriction on $L$?

Answer (score 1):

1. In contrast to what is written in OP's eq. (3), [Hamilton's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamilton%27s_principle), aka. [the principle of stationary action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_action), applies to [boundary value problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary_value_problem) (BVP), not [initial value problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_value_problem) (IVP). Boundary conditions (BC) are necessary in order to derive [Euler-Lagrange (EL) equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation).
2. BVPs are not violating causality by *"seeing into the future",* but merely conditional statements of the form *"if the past and future are such and such, then the period in between is such and such".*
3. Concerning IVP vs. BVP, see also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/38348/2451) related Phys.SE post.
4. OP's last question seems answered by appropriate [uniqueness theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniqueness_theorem) for IVPs.

Comment: It was a misconception from my part. I thought that because what we know are initial positions and momenta then it should be a IVP. But I think my main question still remains for the BVP: *how can I guarantee that I don't have problems with the solutions of the EL equation, like the case of the minimum surface of revolution?*